# Linear system equations

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, linear-programming, numerical-linear-algebra

I need to get, preferably by a numerical method, a solutions of:
$$\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
2\sum_{i=1}^n b_{ik}x_i+x_{n+1}=0&\text{for}& k=1,2\ldots,n\\
\sum_{i=1}^n x_i=0
\end{array}\right.$$
with $(b_{ij})_{1\leq i,j\leq n}$ symmetric.

Is there a numerical method for homogeneous this problem?

Many thanks!

Comment: There must be some kind of a typo in the problem statement. In the equations you only refer to $b_i$, but in the line following the equations you write about $b_{ij}$. Did you want to write $b_{ik}$ instead of $b_ik$?

Comment: In any case, if the post is correct as suggested in the above comment, then this is simply the system
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\begin{matrix}1&1&\dots&1\end{matrix} & 0\\
2B & \begin{matrix}1\\1\\\vdots\\1\end{matrix}
\end{array}\right)
\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\\vdots\\x_n\\x_{n+1}\end{pmatrix} = 0.$$ 
Do you have some other information on the matrix $B$? (In particular, do we know somethings about dimension of the solution space?) I suppose you want to avoid Gaussian elimination and exploit the structure of this matrix in some way.